# Reading a openstreetmap XML file in C++ using eclipse

Tags: c++, xml, eclipse, dom, openstreetmap

I am new to xml. I am trying to read an xml file taken from openstreetmaps. it looks as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
 <bounds minlat="48.3994690" minlon="9.9897780" maxlat="48.3998220" maxlon="9.9898260"/>
 <node id="149248718" lat="48.3994984" lon="9.9897961" user="Matthias Frank" uid="287306" visible="true" version="7" changeset="7966729" timestamp="2011-04-25T18:01:43Z"/>
 <node id="1831376336" lat="48.3995041" lon="9.9898087" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:51Z"/>
 <node id="1831376346" lat="48.3995599" lon="9.9902392" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:52Z"/>
 <node id="1831376331" lat="48.3993243" lon="9.9898198" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:51Z"/>
 <node id="1831376349" lat="48.3996127" lon="9.9906471" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:52Z"/>
 <node id="1831376348" lat="48.3996044" lon="9.9910549" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:52Z"/>
 <node id="1831376418" lat="48.4000685" lon="9.9897909" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:55Z"/>
 <node id="1831376350" lat="48.3996158" lon="9.9908451" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:52Z"/>
 <node id="1831376374" lat="48.3999450" lon="9.9897917" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:54Z"/>
 <way id="172207897" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:02:59Z">
  <nd ref="1831376348"/>
  <nd ref="1831376350"/>
  <nd ref="1831376349"/>
  <nd ref="1831376346"/>
  <nd ref="1831376336"/>
  <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="living_street"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Hintere Rebengasse"/>
  <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
 </way>
 <way id="172207928" user="NUP" uid="168758" visible="true" version="1" changeset="12345652" timestamp="2012-07-19T20:03:01Z">
  <nd ref="1831376331"/>
  <nd ref="1831376336"/>
  <nd ref="1831376374"/>
  <nd ref="1831376418"/>
  <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="living_street"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Pfauengasse"/>
  <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
 </way>
</osm>
```

What is the the simplest and shortest way to read the the data e.g. from node i want to read id, lat, lon and for each node I want to save that information as well. also for elements as "way" I want to read the ref and "tag" elements attached to it.

I am using simple fstream but it doesn't look the most efficient way.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inventing the wheel again you could and should use a XML parser:

http://lars.ruoff.free.fr/xmlcpp/

For light weight parsing I usually use RapidXml. It's fast and is easy to use (at least from my point of view)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an XML parsing library.  Which one is up to you.  Currently, I'm looking at tinyxml but I haven't used it yet so I can't endorse it.  It does look very simple to incorporate into a project though.